# Function TypeError: 'Functional' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, function, google-colaboratory

In google colab, I am working on a deep learning model. I have defined a function with no inputs. I am getting the above error when importing the function.

Code:

```
def model_maker():
  base_model = MobileNet(include_top=False,
                         input_shape = (IMG_WIDTH,IMG_HEIGHT,3))
  for layer in base_model[:]:
    layer.trainable = False
  input = Input(shape=(IMG_WIDTH,IMG_HEIGHT,3))
  custom_model = base_model(input)
  custom_model = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(custom_model)
  custom_model = Dense(64,activation='relu')(custom_model)
  custom_model = Dropout(0.5)(custom_model)
  predictions = Dense(NUM_CLASSES,activation='softmax')(custom_model)
  return Model(inputs=input,outputs=predictions)
# Call the model
model = model_maker()
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.001),
              metrics=['acc'])
```

Present output:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-15-6a346cf661dc> in <module>()
----> 1 model = model_maker()

<ipython-input-11-8157b86f0401> in model_maker()
      3                          input_shape = (IMG_WIDTH,IMG_HEIGHT,3))
      4   # I think we are freezing the inner layers
----> 5   for layer in base_model[:]:
      6     layer.trainable = False
      7   input = Input(shape=(IMG_WIDTH,IMG_HEIGHT,3))

TypeError: 'Functional' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: `for layer in base_model:`?

Comment: @BTables I tried this but same error.

Comment: @BTables mistake has been identified. `for i in base_model.layers[:]`